# I cant remove child of this movie clip upon clicking the back button to go function goHomePage (evt:Event):void{

Tags: actionscript-3, removechild

Help. I need to remove the newContainer(this is a movie clip) after clicking the back button to go back to homepage.
But it just loads the homepage and the newContainer is still there. :( where did i go wrong?

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import fl.motion.MotionEvent;
import flash.net.URLVariables;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flashx.textLayout.elements.Configuration;



var ctr:int = 0;
var now:Date = new Date();


var myurl:String = "http://localhost:8888/eventspictures/getdata.php";


var scriptLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var scriptRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
var newContainer:MovieClip;


scriptRequest.url = myurl + "?ck=" + now.getTime();

scriptLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleLoadSuccess);
scriptLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleError);



scriptRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
scriptLoader.load(scriptRequest);


function handleLoadSuccess(evt:Event):void
{

for (var j:Number = 0; j <4; j++)
{
    var newContainer:MovieClip = new con();

    newContainer.name = String(ctr);

    newContainer.y = j*80 +65;
    newContainer.x= 16;

    stage.addChild(newContainer);






    var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables(evt.target.data);
    trace(variables.output);


    var parse:String = variables.output;
    var parsed:Array = parse.split("<|>");

    var tab:String = '&#09;';
    var eventname:String = '';
    var date:String='';
    var slotsleft:String='';



// different variable names to assign to different column names(etc; eventname, date, slotsleft)
    // loop through.. start from O

        for (var i:Number = 0; i<parsed.length-1; i++)
    {
        trace(parsed[i]);

        var item:String = parsed[i];
        var itemarray:Array = item.split(",");

        eventname +=  itemarray[2] + tab + "<br>";
        date += itemarray[3] + tab;
        slotsleft += itemarray[4] + tab;





        trace(eventname);

        newContainer.eventname_txt.htmlText = eventname;
    newContainer.date_txt.htmlText= date;
    newContainer.slotsleft_txt.htmlText=slotsleft;



}


    }





    //slotsleft_txt.x = 270;
}
function handleError(evt:IOErrorEvent):void
{
}

backbutton_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goHomePage);

function goHomePage (evt:Event):void{

    gotoAndPlay("dashboard");
```

removeChild(newContainer);
    }

```
stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your function `handleLoadSuccess()` you have a loop that creates 4 `MovieClip`'s and adds them to the stage.

But in your `goHomePage()` function you only try to remove one object from the stage.  It turns out this object is probably `null` in your example (trying to remove an object that is `null` should generate an error if you are using the debug Flash player).

The reason it is probably `null` is because you have defined two variables named `newContainer` in your code: one is declared at the beginning of the script, and the second one inside the function `handleLoadSuccess()` (because you are using the keyword `var` on each line).

The variable created inside the function only exists while that function is executing. The variable created outside the function never seems to receive a value.

Two approaches you can use:

**Keep track of the things you add to the stage, by putting them in an `Array`:**

Replace the `newContainer` variable that is outside the function with an `Array` called `containers`:

```
var containers:Array = [];
```

In the function `handleLoadSuccess()`, when you add each `MovieClip` to the stage, also add them to the `containers` array:

```
stage.addChild(newContainer);
containers.push(newContainer);
```

Finally in the function `goHomePage()` iterate over the `containers` array to remove each `MovieClip`:

```
for (var j:int = 0; j < containers.length; j++)
{
    stage.removeChild( containers[j] );

}
// reset the containers array so it's empty for the next time
// and to remove the references to the MovieClips (to prevent a memory leak)
containers=[];
```

**Blindly remove everything from the stage**

If this is accetpable, it is much easier. Just iterate backwards over the children of the stage in your `goHomePage()` function:

```
for (var j:int = stage.numChildren; j >= 1; j--)
{
    stage.removeChildAt(j - 1);
}
```